# E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command, error-handling

when I try to command :

```
 sudo apt update
```

this error was shown:

```
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420190/upgrade-to-22-04-impish-release-no-longer-has-a-release-file . TLDR: Impish is no longer supported and the time to upgrade to a more recent version of Ubuntu was six months before this question was posted.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an option for you, then upgrading to a new release of Linux should solve the problem. It's a bit of a sledgehammer approach, but if you are still stuck and just want to get on with life, then this is an option. As part of the process the repositories will be updated to what is current and supported.

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

Note that this will upgrade your Linux to a newer version if available.

Comment: This has failed for me on Kubuntu 21.10 with the message "Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore."